# Security or performance issue of setting a high timeout for the Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I noticed an error today for one of our long running scripts. A 504 gateway error. I eventually tracked down the issue to being the ELB timing out after 60 seconds whilst our script needs around 5 minutes to perform  it's job.

After increasing the ELB timout to 5 minutes using the AWS console, everything worked perfectly. However, I am now wondering if there are any performance or security issues with this global setting?

I don't have expertise in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No security issues but potentially performance problems if the ELB needs to scale due to increased demand while it still has open connections.  If you aren't using scale events then you will probably see little issue. I'd still recommend revisiting your design to avoid the need to have a long running synchronous request.